# Hide Columns in Document Information Panel, but show in properties panel

Tags: 2010, development, sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, properties

I am trying to hide some columns from view in the DIP, but allow users to change them in the properties panel for the document. I am trying to associate 3 base content types for attaching different document templates with some custom columns. A lot of content types with additional columns with inherit from these in the future, so I don't want to lock down the DIP.

I've tried hiding the columns, but then they don't get included, for some reason, when I try to save it as a document template and re-create the library from that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use InfoPath to customize the DIP and remove the (un)desired fields. They will still show in the properties panel.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The only thing with customising the DIP is that I don't want to have to customise it each time a new column is added to each content type that inherits from it. I am just trying to hide them from that particular view. Is that the only way this can be done?

Comment: The DIP is not a view. It draws directly from the libray's column definitions and it will need to be adjusted when column definitions are changed.

Comment: I know, that's what I'm trying to avoid. There will be a big content type hierarchy. I want the DIP to remain fluid with the changes to the columns. There are a few columns that they want to only be in the properties panel for every content type in the structure. I thought that I could hide them in the base to get that functionality. It may be that it will work when we update the service packs. Unless that is not supposed to happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you hide the columns in the DIP, they are hidden from the properties panel. It acts as a 'soft hide,' so you can still access the columns programatically. They do not appear in the columns for the document library once it is created from a template. You can only access them programaticallly.

We ended up changing the requirements once we realised this. So I don't need a solution to the problem anymore.

Thank you Teylyn for your help :)